# How to synchronize different debian server

Tags: php, debian, tomcat, synchronization

I'm developing a project that consists in a tomcat installation with a web app with many classes and libraries and a php side with many many folder and files.

I've got two server debian wheeze and every time i need to do a change, i necessary need to copy from ftp the edited files from local to each two servers.

If edits has been made on java classes, i need to copy .class of each edited files and restart the two tomcat instances of each server.

Is there a way to synchronize in a simple way two folders from a server to another?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to do this. What's best depend on your situation.

- rsync etc.
- Networked file system like NFS to store the data
- Deployment scripts tied into your VCS (or standalone)
- ...

My first look would be into hooks for your VCS - if done right, a simple `git push` can make all this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I've read about it, but didn't use it yet: [Lsyncd](https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) Maybe this can help you.